# HashiCorp Vault AppRole based authentication Unwrap secret_id got permission denied

Tags: authentication, hashicorp-vault

I am using this code as an example to use AppRole based authentification to Vault. For the secret_id I wanna use an wrapped token to be more secure

```py
    import unittest
    from hvac import Client

    URL = "https://p.vault.myfine-company.de"
    JENKINS_TOKEN = "mylovelytoken"

    def test_ci_startup(self):

      # Jenkins authentifies with token as secure instance
      jenkins_client = Client(url=URL, token=JENKINS_TOKEN)

      # fetch the role_id and stores this somewhere in the image of the app
      resp = jenkins_client.auth.approle.read_role_id(role_name='workshop')
      role_id = resp["data"]["role_id"]

      # get a wrapped secret_id and passes this to the starting app
      result = jenkins_client.write(path='auth/approle/role/workshop/secret-id',wrap_ttl="2s")
      unwrap_token = result['wrap_info']['token']

      # No the app comes in place
      app_client = Client(url=URL) # , token=JENKINS_TOKEN)

      # unwrap the secret_id
      unwrap_response = app_client.sys.unwrap(unwrap_token) # !!! Here I get permission denied
      secret_id = unwrap_response['data']['secret_id']

      # use role_id and secret_id to login
      login_result = app_client.auth.approle.login(role_id=role_id, secret_id=secret_id)
      client_token = login_result['auth']['client_token']

      # Read the database credential
      read_response = app_client.secrets.kv.v2.read_secret_version(path='test/webapp')
      self.assertEqual("users", read_response['data']['data']['db_name'])

      return
```

Unfortunatly when try to unwrap the secret_id with `app_client.sys.unwrap(unwrap_token)` there is an 403 "permission denied" When I use the app_client-Connection with `app_client = Client(url=URL), token=JENKINS_TOKEN)` everything works fine. But this of course this not the way the AppRole based authentication should be used. All this is bases on the following Tutorials and Best Practices :

https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/tutorials/recommended-patterns/pattern-approle
https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/tutorials/auth-methods/approle?in=vault%2Fauth-methods

I think is somewhat related to policies. But I did not find the solution yet.

Comment: Yes the client needs to be authenticated with an associated policy that authorizes token unwrapping. The policy should be in those tutorials you linked at the bottom of the question.

Comment: Yes the tutorial is working as expected. I can fetch a wrapped_token in the first window with TTL say 10s. Then use another window to unwrap, get a secret_id, use it with role_id to get an VAULT_TOKEN and finally use this token to read the secret. It is just my python stuff that gets `permission denied`

Comment: Ok I see the issue now with the "Pull" method implementation: the first client is authorized to unwrap and not the second. The first client unwraps the token and passes to the second client for authentication. The second client is not authenticated at all, and therefore would be unable to unwrap.

Comment: @MattSchuchard see my answer. The second client unwrapps the token and uses this to obtain the `secret-id`. In this case the app does not have the `secret-id` stored somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bash window 1:

```
$ export VAULT_ADDR="https://p.vault.myfine-company.de"
$ export VAULT_TOKEN="my-fine-token"
$ # This creates a secret 
$ vault kv put secret/mysql/webapp db_name="users" username="admin" password="passw0rd" 
$ # this writes the policy to access the secret
$ vault policy write jenkins -<<EOF\n# Read-only permission on secrets stored at 'secret/data/mysql/webapp'\npath "secret/data/mysql/webapp" {\n  capabilities = [ "read" ]\n}\nEOF\n
$ # This creates an approle jenkins
$ vault write auth/approle/role/jenkins token_policies="jenkins" \\n    token_ttl=1h token_max_ttl=4h\n
$ # this reads the role-id
$ vault read auth/approle/role/jenkins/role-id
  Key        Value
  ---        -----
  role_id    fcff5e13-wonderfull-my-fine-role-id
$ This creates a wrapping token with TTL 120s 
$ vault write -wrap-ttl=120s -force auth/approle/role/jenkins/secret-id
  Key                              Value
  ---                              -----
  wrapping_token:                  hvs.wonderfull-msgiIp9nu91c1fLrcwGh4KHGh2cy5HMmw4bkh2-my-fine-wrapping-token
  wrapping_accessor:               ddXZLPFmy-fine-accessor
  wrapping_token_ttl:              2m
  wrapping_token_creation_time:    2022-11-23 12:19:46.958503493 +0000 UTC
  wrapping_token_creation_path:    auth/approle/role/jenkins/secret-id
  wrapped_accessor:                5superp-6-my-fine-wrapped-accessor
```

`role_id` and `wrapping_token` is now used in bash window 2:

```
$ # unwrap token to obtain the secret-id
$ VAULT_TOKEN=hvs.wonderfull-msgiIp9nu91c1fLrcwGh4KHGh2cy5HMmw4bkh2-my-fine-wrapping-token vault unwrap
  Key                   Value
  ---                   -----
  secret_id             ac8b3594-my-wundervolles-secret-id
  secret_id_accessor    485423my-wundervolles-secret-accessor
  secret_id_ttl         0s
$ # login to vault and get a APP_TOKEN to be used to read secrets
$ vault write auth/approle/login role_id=fcff5e13-wonderfull-my-fine-role-id secret_id=ac8b3594-my-wundervolles-secret-id
  Key                     Value
  ---                     -----
  token                   hvs.CAESIEW-so-a-nice-token-lEgXb9ZIf-my-wonderfull-token
  token_accessor          MehfK-my-wonderfull-accessor
  token_duration          1h
  token_renewable         true
  token_policies          ["default" "jenkins"]
  identity_policies       []
  policies                ["default" "jenkins"]
  token_meta_role_name    jenkins
$ export APP_TOKEN=hvs.CAESIEW-so-a-nice-token-lEgXb9ZIf-my-wonderfull-token
$ # Read a secret
$ VAULT_TOKEN=$APP_TOKEN vault kv get secret/mysql/webapp
  ====== Secret Path ======
  secret/data/mysql/webapp
  ======= Metadata =======
  Key                Value
  ---                -----
  created_time       2022-11-23T09:44:24.429733013Z
  custom_metadata    <nil>
  deletion_time      n/a
  destroyed          false
  version            1
  ====== Data ======
  Key         Value
  ---         -----
  db_name     users
  password    passw0rd
  username    admin
```

The advantage with this wrapped_token is that the CI Pipeline passes this short lived token to the app. The app uses this token to retrieve the `secret-id` (by unwrapping it) and performs the login together with the `role-id`to obtain the access token to read the database secret.

**Solution :**

The Problem is solved by providing the `unwrap_token` to `app_client = Client(url=URL) token=unwrap_token` as mentioned in a still open pull-request to hvac (as of 2022-11-30) :

```py
import hvac

client = hvac.Client(url='https://127.0.0.1:8200')
client.token = "hvs.wonderfull-msgiIp9nu91c1fLrcwGh4KHGh2cy5HMmw4bkh2-my-fine-wrapping-token"

# When authenticating with just the wrapping token, should not pass token into unwrap call
unwrap_response = client.sys.unwrap()
print('Unwrapped approle role token secret id accessor: "%s"' % unwrap_response['data']['secret_id_accessor'])
```